# Optimizing for multiple keywords using different internal anchor text for the same page

Tags: seo, google, links, navigation, anchor

I have a website with breadcrumb navigation and an additional header navigation. The header navigation is not static and looks different depending on where on the site it is located.

My idea is to mix the anchor texts in the header navigation and breadcrumb navigation. So for example I have 3 keywords for each page and would mix them just algorithmically. Example: From the navigation i link from 60 pages to one and the same subpage. The anchor texts distribution is 20x KW1, 20x KW2, 20x KW3.

The idea behind is to describe the content wider that the user will find on the subpages. Does someone have any experience with such cases and know of advantages or disadvantages?